# Environment Varible PATH exceeding recommended length solution?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, windows

I am attempting to install Oracle Database 11g on a Windows 7 64x laptop.

I get all the way to step 5 of 8 and I get a fail on Environment variable path "exceeds recommended length"...

I have created a `C:\ODB` directory and have `set ORACLE_HOME=C:\ODB`

I have shortened it as much as possible.

What is the correct way to install Oracle Database 11g on Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PATH environment variable contains all the folders that should be searched for the exe when launching an application if its path is not specified.  Yours would be too long once the Oracle stuff is added.

In Windows 7, there is a control panel applet called System (if memory serves).  In this applet, there is a way to set environment variables - perhaps you have some items in the PATH variable that you are no longer using.  Having said that, unless you understand the implications you likely shouldn't mess with it.

Answer (score 6):

I found the exact solution: and your exactly correct Max Vernon.

"Problem causes problems when installing an Oracle 11g database on a machine which already has a lot of different software installed,
On win 7 64bit, go to PATH variable(Right click on my computer>properties>Advanced system Settings>Advanced Tab>click on Envirnment variable>in system variable - look for Path>

1. When the failure occurs during installation of Oracle 11g, click on cancel, you will need to restart the installation from scratch
2. On win 7 64bit, go to PATH variable(Right click on my computer>properties>Advanced system Settings>Advanced Tab>click on Envirnment variable>in system variable - look for Path>
3. Find the Path environment in the System Variables window and edit it, click on it and select all the values within it,
   paste these into a word document or something and save it. You might wish to see whats needed and what isnt but thats a different problem !
4. Clear the Path environment and simply add a single directory such as c:\Seer
5. Start the installation of Oracle 11g again and sit there and wait while it chunders through the processing.
6. Return to the Environment Variables and paste the originals back after the new ones put in by the installation "

Comment: +1 - I was on my mobile when I answered the question, and was just about to look it up on Windows 7 to provide a cleaner answer!

Answer (score 2):

On Win7 you also must be running this as admin, or it will fail to be able to read the path variable, and install halts.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be because of remote location of Oracle Installer. Copy the installer into location drive and run the installer as Administrator should resolve the issue.